# Broken images after moving blog (Wordpress+Non standard letters issue)

Tags: wordpress, image, migration

So last time I moved my WP blog, all the images with the non-standard letters "å, ä and ö" in their url was broken/gone. Is there any way to easily fix this and recover the images? Note that I can't do it manually since it's a big blog with a ton of pictures, so it has to be a bulk fix. On a sidenote, is there any downside to moving your blog using a plugin instead of using the SQL db backup?

Would be super grateful for help. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your WordPress admin panel.
From the Plugins menu, click Add New.
Type Search and replace, and then click Search Plugins.
Locate the Search and Replace plugin, and then click Install Now.
Click OK.
Click Activate Plugin.
From the Tools menu, click Search and Replace.
Enter your old site's URL in the Search for field. For example, http://olddomainexample.com (no trailing slash).
Enter your new site's URL in the Replaced with field.